# At time n, randomly choose a natural number ≤n. How long is it until a single number is chosen three times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

To clarify, the number ≤n is chosen uniformly at random at each step, and n chooses from the natural numbers beginning with 1.

I wish to determine the expected value of $n$ at which a natural number is chosen three times (for the first time). (I would also ideally like to know how to calculate E(a number being chosen $y$ times))

I calculated $\Pr(\text{hitting a number thrice at } n=x)$ for some low values, but it rapidly becomes a lot to do by hand.

\begin{align*}
\Pr(n=1) &= \Pr(n=2) = 0 \\
\Pr(n=3) &= 1/6 \\
\Pr(n=4) &= 1/6 \\
\Pr(n=5) &= 19/120
\end{align*}

The inspiration for this question refers to the card game Hearthstone and a particular card interaction. See
http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Grim_Patron
http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Bouncing_Blade

The title of this question and the phrasing used throughout is not how I conceived the question, but a reformulation that mjqxxxx posted.

Comment: A simple way to write the problem is the following: "At time $n$, randomly choose a natural number $\le n$.  How long is it until a single number is chosen three times?"

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't think of a simple way to phrase the question so I just did a really long question. I've revised the question to your phrasing.

Comment: @James:  Perhaps it is worth clarifying that your natural numbers begin with $1$, or otherwise with $0$.

Comment: I think $n=5$ should be $19/120$. Simulation suggests the expected value of $n$ should be around $6.3$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out the numerical findings about $\mathbb{E}[N_3]$ by David E is not a coincidence, it is exact!
$$\mathbb{E}[N_3] = \frac{1}{1-\sin(1)}$$

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be a sequence of random variables. For each $n$,
we will assume $X_n$ take value from the set $\langle n \rangle \stackrel{def}{=}\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$ with uniform probability.

After the $n^{th}$ iteration, consider following random variables:

- $Y_{m} = \# \{ i \in \langle n \rangle : X_i = m \}$ be the number of times the number $m$ is chosen.
- $Z_{m} = \# \{ i \in \langle n \rangle : Y_i = m \}$ be the number of numbers which has been chosen $m$ times.

For those configuration where none of the number has been chosen more than twice,
$Z_{k}$ are not independent from each other. In fact, if we know $Z_0 = p$, we will have

$$Z_1 = n - 2p,\quad Z_2 = p\quad\text{ and }\quad Z_k = 0, \forall k > 2$$

For such a configuration, it is clear at the $(n+1)^{th}$ iteration, the probability that

- $Z_0$ remains unchanged is $\frac{p+1}{n+1}$.
- $Z_0$ increases by $1$  is $\frac{n-2p}{n+1}$.
- some number get picked $3$ times is $\frac{p}{n+1}$.

If we define

- $f_{n,p} = \mathbb{P}\left[ Z_0 = p, Z_1 = 2n-p, Z_2 = p, Z_k > 0 \land \forall k > 2 \right]$
- $f_n(z)  = \sum_{p=0}^n f_{n,p} z^p$,
- $F(z,t)  = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z) t^n$

We find $f_{n,p}$ satisfy following recurrence relation:

$$
f_{n+1,p} 
= \frac{p+1}{n+1}f_{n,p} + \frac{n-2(p-1)}{n+1}\begin{cases} f_{n,p-1}, & p > 0\\0, &p = 0\end{cases}\\
\implies 
(n+1) f_{n+1}(z) = 
\left\{ \left(1 + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) 
+ z\left( n - 2z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \right\} f_n(z)
$$
Multiply each term by $t^n$ and sum and notice $f_1(z) = 1$, we find:

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial t} ( F(t,z) - 1 - t )
= \left\{ 
\left(1 + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
+ 
z\left( t\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - 2z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)
\right\} ( F(z,t) - 1)\\
\iff &
\left\{ (1 - zt)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
- (1 + z(1-2z)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\} F(z,t) = 0\\
\iff &
\left\{ (1 - zt)\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
- z(1-2z)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\} \left( \frac{z}{1-2z} F(z,t) \right) = 0
\end{align}
$$
Using method of characteristics, one can show that the general solution of last PDE has the form

$$F(z,t) = \frac{1-2z}{z} \varphi\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2z}}{1+\sqrt{1-2z}}e^{t\sqrt{1-2z}}\right)$$
where $\varphi(\cdots)$ is an arbitrary function. We can determine $\varphi(\cdots)$ by setting to $t = 0$, we have

$$\frac{1-2z}{z} \varphi\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2z}}{1+\sqrt{1-2z}}\right) = F(z,0) = 1$$
After a little bit of algebra, we get
$$F(z,t) = \frac{4u^2 e^{tu}}{((1+u) - (1-u) e^{tu})^2}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
u = \sqrt{1-2z}
$$

Notice for each $n$, $f_n(1) = \sum_{p=0}^n f_{n,p}$ is the probability that none of the numbers has been chosen more than twice. This means
$f_{n-1}(1) - f_n(1)$ is the probability that some "new" number get picked the third times. So the number we want is

$$\mathbb{E}[N_3] = (1-f_1(1)) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty n (f_{n-1}(1) - f_{n}(1))
= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(1) = F(1,1)$$

Substitute this back to our expression of $F(z,t)$, we get

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N_3] 
& = \frac{4i^2 e^i}{((1+i) - (1-i) e^i)^2} = \frac{1}{1-\sin(1)}\\
& \approx 6.307993516443740027513521739824160128971342...
\end{align}
$$
There are other interesting statistics one can gather from $F(z,t)$. For example,
the generating function for the "survival" probability $f_n(1)$ is

$$P_{survival}(t) \stackrel{def}{=} 1 + \sum_{n=0}f_n(1)t^n = F(1,t) = \frac{1}{1-\sin(t)}$$

and that for the probability for "death at $3^{rd}$ strike" at step $n$ is

$$\begin{align}
P_{3^{rd} strike}(t) & \stackrel{def}{=} (1-f_1(1)) t + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (f_{n-1}(1) - f_{n}(1)) t^n\\
& = (t - 1) P_{survival}(t) + 1 = \frac{t-1}{1-\sin(t)} + 1
\end{align}$$

If one throw the last expression to a CAS and ask it to compute the Taylor expansion, one get

$$\begin{align}
P_{3^{rd} strike}(t) = 
& \frac{1}{6}t^3 + \frac{1}{6}t^4 + \frac{19}{120}t^5 + \frac{47}{360}t^6
  +\frac{173}{1680}t^7 + \frac{131}{1680} t^8 +\frac{20903}{362880}t^9\\
& +\frac{75709}{1814400}t^{10} + \frac{1188947}{39916800}t^{11}
  +\frac{2516231}{119750400}t^{12} + \cdots
\end{align}$$
The coefficient for $t^k$ matches the numbers $Pr[N_3 = k]$ listed in another answer.

**Update 1**

Let's become *Don Quixote* and challenge the harder problem of computing $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$ for $y > 3$.

Similar to $y = 3$, one can setup a PDE for the generating functions.
However, if one only want $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$, there is no need to solve the PDE completely. One can use the method of characteristics and express $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$
in terms of solutions of some ODE.

The derivation is a mess. I'll spare you all boring details and here is the recipe:

1. The case for $y = 4$ is straight forward, one can show that
   $$\mathbb{E}[N_4] = \frac{\rho^3 + 3\rho + 2}{6}
   \;\;\text{ where }\;\;
   \rho \;\;\text{ satisfies }\;\;
   1 = \int_1^\rho \frac{6ds}{s^3 + 3s + 2}
   $$
2. For general $y$, setup a system of ODE in $y+1$ varibles $\psi, t, z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_{y-1}$:
   $$
   \frac{d\psi}{d\tau} = z_1 \psi,\quad
   \frac{dt}{d\tau} = t z_1-1\quad
   \quad\text{ and }\quad
   \frac{dz_k}{d\tau} = 
   \begin{cases}
   -z_k(z_k - z_{k+1}), & k < y-1\\
   -z_k^2, & k = y-1
   \end{cases}
   $$
   If one start integrate this system of ODE using initial values
   $$( \psi, t, z_1, \ldots, z_{y-1} ) = (1, 1, \ldots, 1 )\quad\text{ at }\quad \tau = 0$$
   to the point $\rho$ where $t(\rho) = 0$, then $\psi(\rho)$ will be equal to the
   number $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$ we seek.

Following are some numerical results. The label $\verb/R1/$ and $\verb/R2/$ indicate which recipe has been used to compute the result. The number behind 
the label $\verb/R2/$ is the maximum time-step used in numerically integration.

$$\begin{array}{c:l:l}
y & \mathbb{E}[N_y] & \verb/methodology/\\
\hline
2 & 6.30799351644374 & \verb/exact/ = \frac{1}{1-\sin 1}\\
2 & 6.3079930650     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-4})\\
2 & 6.3079935164     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-6})\\
\hline
3 & 13.77250982352477 & \verb/R1/ \\
3 & 13.7725078084     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-4})\\
3 & 13.7725098234     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-6})\\
\hline
4 & 29.1475420469     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-4})\\
4 & 29.1475467696     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-6})\\
\hline
5 & 60.5714357748     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-4})\\
5 & 60.5714459868     & \verb/R2 /(10^{-6})\\
\hline
6 & 124.4243032167    & \verb/R2 /(10^{-4})\\
6 & 124.4243208364    & \verb/R2 /(10^{-6})
\end{array}
$$

As one can see, $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$ seems to approximately double for each increment of $y$.

**Update 2**

It turns out part of the complicated ODE in *Update 1* can be solved explicitly.
For any given $y \ge 3$ and $k = 1,2,\ldots,y-1$, we have

$$z_{k}(s) = \frac{e_{y-k-1}(s)}{e_{y-k}(s)}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
e_m(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
The new simplified recipe is

$$\mathbb{E}[N_y] = e_{y-1}(\rho)
\quad\text{ where }\quad 
\rho \quad\text{ is root of the equation }\quad
1 = \int_0^\rho \frac{ds}{e_{y-1}(s)}
$$
Following is some numerical results computed using this new recipe.
All numbers has been truncated to 6-decimals places for easy comparison. 
As one can see from the $3^{rd}$ column, $2^y$ is a reasonable decent 
$1^{st}$ order approximation for $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$ as $y$ grows.

$$\begin{array}{r:r:l}
y & \mathbb{E}[N_y]  & \mathbb{E}[N_y]/2^y\\
\hline
3 &     6.307993 & 0.788499\\
4 &    13.772509 & 0.860781\\
5 &    29.147546 & 0.910860\\
6 &    60.571445 & 0.946428\\
7 &   124.424320 & 0.972065\\
8 &   253.615739 & 0.990686\\
9 &   514.170899 & 1.004240\\
10&  1038.407593 & 1.014069\\
11&  2091.272044 & 1.021128\\
12&  4202.932580 & 1.026106\\
13&  8433.748402 & 1.029510\\
14& 16903.678242 & 1.031718\\
15& 33849.909944 & 1.033017
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Fantastic. Haven't touched generating functions in a probability context since early undergrad days, but when I see an answer like this, I remember why I (in my limited experience) used to really enjoy using them.

Out of interest, would you imagine you would get a nice solution for $y=4$ also? I guess the recursion would need 3 recursion variables, so may give a less nice PDE?

Comment: @DavidE Yes, for $y = 4$, it is not that hard to setup a PDE with $3$ recursion variables. However, solving it is a completely different story. I was actually surprised when I'm able to solve the $y = 3$ PDE. If you didn't point out the simple form of $\mathbb{E}(N_3)$, I probably won't retry to solve that for that many times.

Comment: RE Update 2 - that is really nice - what a neat form! I really wanted there to be a really neat answer for general $y$, and there it is. Great job. I've really enjoyed seeing the solutions here, so thanks for editing your answer etc as you find out more!

Answer (score 7):

Reprenting the health of each Patron by $y$, and the quantity of interest by $N_y$, I get:
\begin{align*}
\Pr[ N_3 = 1 ] &= 0 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 2 ] &= 0 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 3 ] &= 1/6 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 4 ] &= 1/6 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 5 ] &= 19/120 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 6 ] &= 47/360 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 7 ] &= 173/1680 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 8 ] &= 131/1680 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 9 ] &= 20903/362880 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 10 ] &= 75709/1814400 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 11 ] &= 1188947/39916800 \\ 
\Pr[ N_3 = 12 ] &= 2516231/119750400 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 13 ] &= 3386161/230630400 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 14 ] &= 147882737/14529715200 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 15 ] &= 1832969507/261534873600 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 16 ] &= 570448019/118879488000 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 17 ] &= 1162831155151/355687428096000 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 18 ] &= 1014210646079/457312407552000 \\
\Pr[ N_3 = 19 ] &= 4674810997597/3119105138688000 \\
\end{align*}

$\mathbb{E}[N_3] =  6.30799351644$ (calculated  with $x < 100$)

This is calculated recursively by saving the number of Patrons with 2,1,0 hits respectively in a tuple (a,b,c), and calculating the possibilities recursively.

For reference, we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N_2] &= e \qquad \text{(easyish exercise)} \\
\mathbb{E}[N_3] &=  6.30799351644 \dots \\
\mathbb{E}[N_4] &= 13.7725 \dots \\
\mathbb{E}[N_5] &\approx 30
\end{align*}

Getting an exact answer for $y \geq 5$ is beyond my computational power, but I expect $\mathbb{E}[N_5] \approx 30$. Convergence really slows as $y$ grows. (As do the number of cases, and the size of numerators / denominators of fractions for exact calculations).

<del>IMHO the chances of there existing a "nice" closed form for $y > 2$ are slim.</del>

Though, interestingly, putting $\mathbb{E}[N_3]$ into the inverse symbolic calculator https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc gives $\mathbb{E}[N_3] \approx 1/(1-\sin(1))$ to insanely high accuracy... <del>but I imagine this is almost certainly a coincidence.</del>

*EDIT*: Turns out I am completely wrong about this - this is exact - see achille hui's answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243379/200767

**Rough bound on $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$**

We can loosely bound $\mathbb{E}[N_y]$ though, as observe that the expected number of times the first patron is hit after $n$ total hits is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \sim \ln n \to \infty
\end{align*}

So, in particular, very loosely, if $\ln n \geq y$, we expect the first Patron will have been killed. Ie $\mathbb{E}[N_y] \leq O(e^y)$.

Code (Python 2.7):

```
from fractions import Fraction
N = 100;
y = 5;

probs = [{}] * (N+1);
probs[0] = {tuple([0] * y): Fraction(1, 1)};
death_prob = [Fraction(0,1)] * (N+1);

for n in range(1, N+1): # n-1 hits so far. Now calculating nth hit
    probs[n] = {};
    for prev_hit_counts, prob in probs[n-1].iteritems():
        prob_scaler = prob / n;

        for i in range(y): # A Patron who has already been hit i times gets hit
            if prev_hit_counts[i] == 0 and i != 0: # Check such a Patron exists
                continue

            new_hit_counts = list(prev_hit_counts);
            new_hit_counts[0] += 1; # Add a new Patron who has not been hit
            probability = new_hit_counts[i] * prob_scaler; # Probability of hitting such a Patron

            if i == y-1:
                # A Patron who has been hit y-1 times gets hit... we lose.
                death_prob[n] += probability;
            else:
                new_hit_counts[i] -= 1;
                new_hit_counts[i+1] += 1;
                if tuple(new_hit_counts) not in probs[n]:
                    probs[n][tuple(new_hit_counts)] = Fraction(0,1);
                probs[n][tuple(new_hit_counts)] += probability;


for n in range(1,N+1):
    if n <= 20:
        print '\\Pr[N_{0} = {1}] &= {2} = {3} \\\\'.format(y,n,death_prob[n],float(death_prob[n]));
    else:
        print '\\Pr[N_{0} = {1}] &= {2} \\\\'.format(y,n,float(death_prob[n]));

print '\\mathbb{{E}}[N_{0}] = {1}'.format(y,float(sum([n * i for n,i in enumerate(death_prob)])));
print 'Using 0 <= x <= {0}'.format(N);
```

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[N_3] = \frac{1}{1-\sin(1)}$ is not a coincidence, it is exact!

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic. Haven't got a chance to read through it probably now, but will look forward to reading it later!

Comment: Looks like for $y = 4$, the OGF for survival probabilities satisfy a functional relation:

$$P_{survival}(t) = \frac{\rho^3 + 3\rho + 2}{6}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
\rho \;\;\text{ is the root for }\;\;
t = \int_1^\rho \frac{6ds}{s^3 + 3s + 2}
$$
Solving $\rho$ numerically for $t = 1$, give us
$$
\rho \approx 4.089005680457094\quad\implies\quad
\mathbb{E}[N_4] = P_{survival}(1) \approx 13.77250982352477$$ Do you have more digits for $\mathbb{E}[N_4]$?

Comment: Just wanted to say, your answer is fantastic!

With my computation (which could really use some optimizations), it begins to rapidly slow down after $x \approx 120$, and the only numbers I could digits of $\mathbb{E}[N_4]$ I could be sure of were the ones quoted (I was fairly certain on 13.772509, but it was awfully close to 13.77251, so thought it best to stay safe). Looks like you've got the right answers though for sure! Pretty interesting how it doubles (ish) each time. Seems like the $O(e^y)$ bound is surprisingly close, at least in form.